# Unity 2D Second Chance for Jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm new to game dev, and I'm working on a simple 2d platformer game with a player that moves and jumps. But the issue is that the jump must be precise. My script and method is simply a capsule collider set to is trigger and when the player is touching ground, he can jump, but as I said it's precise. If there's any way to give the player some moments after leaving the ground to jump and another chance, please help me. Thanks for your help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.UIElements.Experimental;

public class RabbitMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator animator;

    private float horizontal;
    public float speed;
    public float jump;
    private bool facingRight = true;
    private bool isGrounded = true;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump));
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", !isGrounded);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (horizontal > 0 && !facingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        if (horizontal < 0 && facingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));
        animator.SetFloat("yVelocity", rb.velocity.y);
    }

    public void Flip()
    {
        Vector2 currenScale = gameObject.transform.localScale;
        currenScale.x *= -1;
        gameObject.transform.localScale = currenScale;

        facingRight = !facingRight;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor"))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", !isGrounded);

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor"))
        {
            isGrounded = false;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", !isGrounded);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried messing around and came up with two ideas. The first is to make the capsule's width longer and it worked, but now the player can jump while standing besides a wall. And the second was to create some kind of float for the number of chances, which I believe is the true solution, and couldn't do it.

Comment: `If there's any way to give the player some moments after leaving the ground to jump and another chance` .. yes, add a counter .. increase it when you apply jumping, check if you still can jump before apply jumping ... and reset the counter when you are grounded again .. the counter should probably be an `int` not a `float` though

Answer (score 0):

jumping in 2d games is very important, so I highly reccomend you put a lot of time and effort into it (mine is over 500 lines long) If you ever need a reference heres my jumpcheck function which you can use to help, however you may find it a bit confusing:

```
private void JumpUpdate() {
    if (grounded) {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
            jumpTime = 0;
            jumping = true;
            jumps--;
        }
    }
    else if (jumps > 0) {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
            jumpTime = 0;
            jumping = true;
            jumps--;
        }
    }
    else if (!grounded && coyoteTimeCount > 0 && jumps > 0) {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
            jumpTime = 0;
            jumping = true;
            jumps--;
        }
    }
    else if (!grounded && dashing && jumps > 0) {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
            dashing = false;
            dashCount = dashTime;
            jumpTime = 0;
            jumping = true;
            jumps--;
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump") ) {
        jumpTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")) {
        jumping = false;
    }

    bool limitReached = false;
    if (jumping && jumpTime >= maxJumpTime) {
        limitReached = true;
    }
    else if (!limitReached && jumping && jumpTime < maxJumpTime) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    }
    else if (limitReached) {
        jumping = false;
    }
}
```

its way too long to go into detail, but if you ever want to try and figure it out, then there you go.
*Anyway*, back to your problem. To add more than one jump, we can add a few lines of code. First of all we need some variables for the inspector:

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public Animator animator;

private float horizontal;
public float speed;
public float jump;
private bool facingRight = true;
private bool isGrounded = true;

public int jumpCount = 2;
private int jumpAmount;
```

Next, we can reset the jumps amount when the player is grounded

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor"))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", !isGrounded);
        jumpsAmount = jumpCount;
    }
}
```

By the way jumps amount is the players current jump amount, and jumps count is the value we can change in the inspector, which is what we set the jump amount to when grounded.
Anyway, the last thing to do is add an alternative inside of the Update function, checking if were not grounded, and pressing jump, but we still have jumps left. Also dont forget to decrease the jumps amount by 1 in the initial jump too.

```
void Update()
{
    horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded == true)
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump));
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", !isGrounded);
        jumpsAmount--;
    }
    else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded == false && jumpsAmount > 0)
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump));
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", !isGrounded);
        jumpsAmount--;
    }
}
```

One last thing, this code is clearly from a Youtube tutorial, but its probably quite outdated, for booleans you dont need to use == true or == false, so you can change `isGrounded == true` to just isGrounded, or !isGrounded. ! means the opposite, so for example !Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") would be true when were not pressing jump.
So we can change it one last time to this:

```
void Update()
{
    horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump));
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", !isGrounded);
        jumpsAmount--;
    }
    else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !isGrounded && jumpsAmount > 0)
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump));
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", !isGrounded);
        jumpsAmount--;
    }
}
```

Any issues feel free to reply and ill try my best to help.

Comment: I really do appreciate your answer and help. Anyways, I tried updating the code and the problem is now solved; however, the player have the ability to jump twice even in the air now, and that's smth I don't think of adding. For now, I might do more research or end up as it is. Thanks again.

Comment: instead of using `if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor"))`, have you tried [Physics2D.OverlapBox()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html)

Comment: Not really, I see it difficult. In addition, I was searching and found this question in unity discussions https://discussions.unity.com/t/creating-a-delay-after-being-grounded-so-the-player-can-still-jump-while-falling/225973. It happens to be what I was looking for, and I tried to apply it, then the player stopped jumping. I don't understand it very well.

Comment: I'm really sorry for taking from your time, but I fixed the problem and the player now jumps even after 0.5 seconds, and that is the problem now bc he can spam space bar for example and jump pretty high for 0.5 seconds and then fall. Any thoughts :)

Comment: perhaps you mean coyote time, if so look that up on youtube and you should be able to find a tutorial, the script i gave should retain a second jump after falling off a surface because of the `else if` that checks to see if you're in the air, pressing jump, and still have jumps left. Could you share your whole script again? Edit: dont worry about time, im happy to help

Comment: You sort of confused me with the question, i thought you just wanted to give the player a double jump, sorry about that.

Comment: I owe you a life man. You're right, it was coyote time. All of this searching just for a single term. Thanks for everything you did. Edit : Idk if you're ok with this, but I'm willing to share with you my game when it's done :⁠^⁠)

Comment: sure man, just let me know when its finished and you can like email it to me maybe?

Comment: I also have an advanced camera controller if your interested, theres a couple bugs and i havnt finished the documentation yet, but heres the [github repo](https://github.com/CodeMax0/CC-2D) if your interested, it has functionalities like dynamic zooming, snapping to points when your close, and a few more things

Comment: We can find a way to talk. Also, I will be checking your repo and trying to implement it.

Comment: okay, let me know if you have any issues.